# Specify the form theme of a specified entity in Symfony 2

Tags: forms, symfony, themes

I am working on a form quite complicated.

This form is based on an `OngletFichier` `Entity` with its form Builder :

`$builder
            ->add('traitement')
            ->add('ligneEntetes');
        $builder->add('colonnesOnglet', 'collection', array('type' => new ColonneOngletType()
            ));`

As you can see, in this Entity Form, I got a list of `ColonneOnglet` which is an other entity.

---

It looks like something like that :

**Entity Form**

- SimpleAttribute of `OngletFichier` (text input)
- SimpleAttribute of `OngletFichier` (text input)
- `ColonneOnglet` (which have its own attributes, its own input)
- `ColonneOnglet` (which have its own attributes, its own input)
- `ColonneOnglet` (which have its own attributes, its own input)

---

I need to define a special form theme for each `ColonneOnglet` to organize its inputs, and to put it in red or not depending on one of its attribute.

I am quite lost with form theming.

I found an example but I don't know if it can answer my problem : http://symfony2-document.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html

Thanks in advance for helping me !

EDIT : 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field
This works easily !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you've found is good, but I think this section of the manual fits better: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field
So the easiest way is to create separate file with form theme and import it into template using
`form_theme form 'Path:To:theme.html.twig'`. You can also define your styling inside the template itself and import using this directive: `form_theme form _self`, but be aware that in order for this to work the template must extend another one.

Comment: Perfect ! After a little work I managed to make this work ! Thanks !